# Упрощение сетки меша триангуляцией

Tags: алгоритм, unity3d, математика, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Как работает алгоритм упрощения полигональной сетки модели триангуляцией Делоне?
Как именно из сетки первой модели можно получить такую же сетку как у второй без потери формы геометрии?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Триангуляция Делоне для многоугольника с дырками работает очень сложно. Объяснение займёт четыре лекции минимум. Самостоятельно её реализовать сложно. Ищите готовое решение.

Comment: Вам не нужна триангуляция Делоне. "Простой" алгоритм: удаляете любую внутреннюю вершину меша. Её соседи образуют многоугольник. Его триангулируете. Продолжаете пока есть внутренние вершины. Это тоже сложно, но подъёмно.

Comment: Когда кончились внутренние вершины, удаляете вершину на границе. Вершина должна соединять два сонаправленных граничных отрезка. Их заменяете на один отрезок. Получившийся многоугольник триангулируете.

Comment: Если  у вас осталась смелость, я помогу. Но стековерфлоу не место для таких упражнений. :)

Comment: За счет того что изначальный меш из тайлов, вычислить лишние вершины проще простого, не считая диагональных ребер, все лишние внутренние имеют по 4 связи, а лишние внешние ровно одну связь с лишним внутренним. Свези между оставшимися находятся по цепочке связей, горизонтальным и вертикальным. Оставшиеся цепочки остается задать найденному в интернете алгоритму.

Comment: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#Section_2D_Triangulations_Constrained

Comment: Легче тогда наверное определить замкнутые вершины границы модели и вершины границ отверстий а после уже отбрасывать вершины с со направленными отрезками 
В итоге останутся упрощённые границы которые возможно соединить триангуляцией
Как думаете такое может сработать?

Comment: Направление верное.